# Matlab: Unique Matrix Generation from Concatenation?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

Lets say I have a simple 2D array A:

```
A = [0.25 0.3; 0.1 0.5];
```

and I want to concatenate a third row with every element-by-element combination of the following vectors:

```
B = 0:0.1:1;
C = 0:0.1:1;
```

to make 121 unique matrices. For example:

```
A_prime = [0.25 0.3; 0.1 0.5; 0 0];
```

would be one such matrix.

I would like to avoid the use of explicit for-loops, if possible, and either use arrayfun or cellfun to do this.

I know meshgrid would provide all unique combination of B and C, and I could define a function to perform  concatenation on A and an element of B,C respectively. That is:

```
[b_mesh, c_mesh] = meshgrid(B,C);
myfun = @(A,b,c) [A; b,c];
```

but arrayfun will result in the error:

```
arrayfun(myfun, A, b_mesh, c_mesh)

Error using arrayfun
All of the input arguments must be of the same size and shape.
Previous inputs had size 2 in dimension 1. Input #3 has size 11
```

which makes sense. So, is there a similar implementation to generate all unique matrices that keeps dimensions consistent?

Another idea I had would be to potentially generate a larger matrix where every 3x3 sub-matrix is 1 of the unique matrices I am looking for and then extract each as needed.

Thanks!

Comment: arrayfun and celfun *are* loops. You just don't see them. Loops are fast in MATLAB since few years ago.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I explained this to my colleagues, but alas here I am :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `meshgrid` + `cellfun` like below

```
[b,c] = meshgrid(B,C);
Z = [b(:),c(:)];
A_primes = cellfun(@(x) [A;x], mat2cell(Z,ones(1,size(Z,1)),size(Z,2)),'UniformOutput', false);
```

such that

```
>> A_primes
A_primes =
{
  [1,1] =

     0.25000   0.30000
     0.10000   0.50000
     0.00000   0.00000

  [2,1] =

     0.25000   0.30000
     0.10000   0.50000
     0.00000   0.10000

  [3,1] =

     0.25000   0.30000
     0.10000   0.50000
     0.00000   0.20000

  [4,1] =

     0.25000   0.30000
     0.10000   0.50000
     0.00000   0.30000

  [5,1] =

     0.25000   0.30000
     0.10000   0.50000
     0.00000   0.40000

  [6,1] =

     0.25000   0.30000
     0.10000   0.50000
     0.00000   0.50000

....
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative using `repmat` and `permute` that builds a 3d matrix such that each 2d plane is one combination:

```
A = [0.25 0.3; 0.1 0.5];
[b_mesh, c_mesh] = meshgrid(B,C);
A_prime = [repmat(A, 1, 1, numel(b_mesh)); permute([b_mesh(:), c_mesh(:)], [3 2 1])];
```

Result:

```
A_prime =

ans(:,:,1) =

   0.25000   0.30000
   0.10000   0.50000
   0.00000   0.00000

ans(:,:,2) =

   0.25000   0.30000
   0.10000   0.50000
   0.00000   0.10000

ans(:,:,3) =

   0.25000   0.30000
   0.10000   0.50000
   0.00000   0.20000

ans(:,:,4) =

   0.25000   0.30000
   0.10000   0.50000
   0.00000   0.30000

...
```

Individual combinations can be retrieved using the 3rd index:

```
A_prime(:,:,112)
ans =

   0.25000   0.30000
   0.10000   0.50000
   1.00000   0.10000
```